# populating iframe with content from POST

Tags: php, jquery, html

I need to display content that was posted from the previous page within iframe. Is it possible?

The content will have HTML tags.

The reason why I need iframe, because it will also have reference to CSS. If I just echo it on page, then it will make problems with CSS style of the main webpage. The only sollution I have found is to use iframe.

Comment: unless you have a really, really good reason: avoid iframes. your reason is not that good.

Comment: whe the reason is not good?
the problem is that I have external files with externa css, if I use those css on my webpage, then all page css are broken, but I need somehow to include those css on to page affecting just div (I thought that this could be done only via iframe)

Comment: download the css and all external files?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just correct your CSS?

FWIW, I don't think you are able to POST data to anything inside an iFrame, especially if you don't have control over the iFrame content.

Answer (score 0):

Iframes link to a URL.

So if you can save the post data into a file on your server and then use ajax or refresh the page to inject the url to that file on the iframe, then you will be sorted.